# i read a makefike for some source code, but have some problems when understanding it

Tags: makefile

```
C=edgelist.c geometry.c heap.c main.c memory.c output.c voronoi.c 
O=edgelist.o geometry.o heap.o main.o memory.o output.o voronoi.o

tt: voronoi t
    voronoi -t <t >tt
voronoi: $O
    cc -o voronoi $O -lm
$O:vdefs.h

voronoi.tar : $C vdefs.h Makefile Doc t
    tar -cf voronoi.tar $C vdefs.h Makefile Doc t

mailable:   $C vdefs.h Makefile t
    bundle $C vdefs.h Makefile t > mailable
```

Can some body explain something for me?

voronoi.tar is the tar archive of all the source code. here lines relating the voronoi.tar take what effect?

and mailable related lines take what effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indented line is the line that will be executed.  $C will expand to the list of .c files given there at the top.  First it will check whether the dependencies (the $C files, vdefs.h, Makefile, Doc, and t) are newer than voronoi.tar is.  If they are (or if voronoi.tar doesn't yet exist), it will (re-)compress the files into the archive.  If they aren't, it will do nothing.